# Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is periodic with period $R >0$. How do I see that $f(x+nR) = f(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is periodic with period $R >0$.

How do I then formally see that $f(x+nR) = f(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$ ?

I see that $f(x) = f(x + nR - nR)$, but how can I proceed ?

Comment: Induction.${{}}$

Comment: $f(x)=f(x+R)=f(x+2R)=f(x+3R)=...$

Comment: Use the definition of periodicity?

Comment: Take, for example, $\sin\left(x+2\pi n\right),\:n\in\mathbb{Z}$...

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is to write that $f\left(x-nR\right)=f\left(x\right)$
  for all integer $n\geq0$
 , then you can just recall $y=x-nR$
  and write$$f\left(x-nR\right)=f\left(y\right)=f\left(y+nR\right)=f\left(x-nR+nR\right)=f\left(x\right).$$

Comment: I like this, induction is unnecessary.

Comment: Of course, this is after proving that $f(x + nR) = f(x)$ if $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: You are right, of course ; I guessed that it was clear for user111854.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ periodic means $\forall x$ we have $f(x+R)=f(x)$ assume $f(x+(n-1)R)=f(x)$ we then have $$\begin{align}f(x+nR)&=f(x+(n-1)R+R)\\&=f(x+(n-1)R)\\&=f(x)\end{align}$$ and we have just proven by induction the identity $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
To prove it for relative number we just replace $n$ with $-n$ and start with $f(x)=f(x-R+R)=f(x-R)$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at this for $n \in \Bbb N$:

Notice that $f(x + nR) = f(x + \underbrace{R + R + \dots + R}_{n \text{ times}})$.

Now, if $y = x + \underbrace{ R + R + \dots + R}_{n - 1 \text{ times}}$, then we get:

$f(x + nR)$

$ = f(x + \underbrace{R + R + \dots + R}_{n \text{ times}}) $

$= f( x + \underbrace{ R + R + \dots + R}_{n - 1 \text{ times}} + R)$

$ = f(y + R) $

$= f(y)$

$= f(x + \underbrace{ R + R + \dots + R}_{n - 1 \text{ times}})$

since $f$ has period $R$.  But you can repeat this again, letting $y$ be $x$ plus the first $n - 2$ of the $R$'s and use periodicity to show the above is equal to $f( x + \underbrace{ R + R + \dots + R}_{n - 2 \text{ times}})$.  Since $n$ is finite, you only have to do this finitely many times, and you will end up (after $n-1$ steps) at $f(x)$, which would show $f(x + nR) = f(x)$.

---

Now that we did it for $n \in \Bbb N$, if you have a negative integer $z$, note that $f(x + zR) = f(x - nR)$ where $n$ is the positive version of $z$.

But $f(x - nR ) = f(x \underbrace{- R - R - R - \dots - R}_{n \text{ times}}) = f(x \underbrace{- R - R - R - \dots - R}_{n \text{ times}} + R)$ (by periodicity), and you can keep adding $R$ to the input $n$ times to get $f(x - nR) = f(x)$.

So, that shows, by cases, that $f(x + nR) = f(x)$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: I just want to comment that my answer is unnecessarily long, though I was trying to explain the idea.  You can prove this more rigorously and cleanly by seeing both answers posted by marwalix (for $n \in \Bbb N$) and Nicolas (for the negative integer case).